# Where is account login template under mezzanine?

Tags: django

I'm trying to look for the login page. I've created a folder `registeration/login.html` under templates, but it doesn't read my updated file at all.

Secondly, there's a button that says login but takes me to `accounts/login` page, how do I just forward the url to `accounts/login` then? and where do i customize the login page? I've tried creating an `accounts/login`under templates, that doesn't work.

urls.py
`url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),`

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to check out the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L49) of the framework when you're looking for the answer. In `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` default template is:

```
template_name = 'registration/login.html'
```

Comment: like i said in the post, ive already modified that file. when i remove the file, it says not found, so it is obviously looking at it.

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. So, the edits you're doing to the template file are not shown on the page? But when you remove the template, it responds with 404, am I right? I propose you to run server on different port (there was a bug, it was about static files, not templates, but who knows) with `python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8001`. Also check if your template folder is in `TEMPLATES` in the `settings.py` file (although you have that 404 error). The button is acually a submit button which takes you to the forms `action` attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

Comment: Also you could try to force refresh the page, ignoring browser cache with `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score 0):

{% url 'login' %}

Use to retrieve pages from template (html)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is very late, but will hopefully be helpful for others facing similar issue.

This is the [Mezzanine source code](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/accounts/templates/accounts/account_login.html) for login page which Mezzanine renders by default.

So, you can do something like

```
python manage.py collecttemplates -t accounts/account_login.html
```

to copy the above file to your app template directory, and modify the copied file as per your needs.

***Bonus***: You can find other account related templates (like sign up, password reset, etc.) [here](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/tree/master/mezzanine/accounts/templates/accounts).